# AngularJS Memory Leak, even in basic code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, memory-leaks

I have inherited an AngularJS project which apparently has a memory leak in it.  In production, it's bad enough to crash a browser if enough instances are run, which can happen.

I've read a lot about leaks in Javascript in the last couple of days, as well as pitfalls in AngularJS. I've still not been able to find the leak, unfortunately.  Doing what I might do in C, I got the program down to almost nothing, to see if it's still leaking.  It's very little, but it's something.

As shown in the code below, I hit an endpoint every 10 seconds... and basically just count the keys in the payload.  Nothing fancy.  I've cut out all 3rd party modules that were in use.  The only thing that should be here is Angular (1.5.8), jquery, and bootstrap.

I'm not well-versed in Google Dev Tools, but I have done a few things. 1, is the Task Manager.  The code below seems to leak about 1k every few minutes. ("live" value in JavascriptMemory column seems to go up 1k even after I force garbage collections). Obviously not bad, but as someone whose main schtick is not front end (or even Javascript for that matter), I'm unsure if this is expected/acceptable.

Secondly, I took two heap snapshots. (Sorry, proxy prohibits me from using any image hoster that I know of).  The main thing I see is after a few minutes, array shows a size delta of +1080.  However, I don't really know what I'm looking for.

As one could imagine, as we add back in production code, the leak becomes far more visible... even to the end user.

Any help (even general) is appreciated.

leak_test.js

```
var app = angular.module('modal.editing', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap'])
   .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

function MainCtrl ($scope, $http, $q, $timeout) {

  $scope.update_ms = 10000;

  $scope.handle_data = function(data) {
    console.log('Got ' + Object.keys(data).length + ' objects in handle_data()');
  };

  $scope.reload_entries = function() {
    var the_url = '/api/1/list';
    $http.get(the_url)
    .success(
      function (list) {
        $scope.handle_data(list.data);
        $timeout(function() { $scope.reload_entries(); }, $scope.update_ms);
      })
    .error(function volume_list_error_cb() {
      $scope.addAlert('Error: GET /api/1/list; Can\'t get current volume list!', 'danger');
      $timeout(function() { $scope.reload_entries(); }, $scope.update_ms);
      });
  };

  $scope.reload_entries();
}
```

For simplicity sake, here is the HTML that's generated:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Leak Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
    <script src="/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
<body>
</body>
<script src="/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="/angular-ui-grid/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.min.js"></script>

<a href="recon_grid">Recon Grid</a>
<h1>DC Recon by Traded Volume Grid</h1>
<h3 class="blue" id="d8_header">Last Update: Thu May 03 2018 13:40:57 GMT-0500 (CDT)</h3>
<div class="volume_grid_container">
  <html ng-app="modal.editing">
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="alert.html">
    <div class="alert" role="alert">
      <div ng-transclude></div>
    </div>
  </script>

  <div alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" ngMaxlength="3" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</div>
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
  </body>
  </html>
</div>
<script src="/javascripts/leak_test.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where do you have $scope.addAlert function defined - in parent scope ?

Comment: Yes, I do -- sorry for including that.  It's pretty basic and I'm sure isn't part of the issue.  Someone posted an answer here that calling timeout() recursively was not good, as all the memory in the stack would be incremented each call.  That definitely seems to have helped, although letting it run over night, it still seemed to grow about 200k in 12 hours.